Flutter - Foreground service stop the bluetooth/ble connection
BLE device which was connected using flutter_reactive_ble library disconnect automatically when the app restored from background, such as lock screen and restore or move to other app and return.
So, I checked my code and noticed that when the app restored, my background service will be stopped.
There is no problem in iOS, only in android.
This is my bluetooth connect code.
deviceStream = flutterReactiveBle
    .connectToDevice(
        id: device.id, connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5))
    .listen(
  (connectionState) {
    if (connectionState.connectionState ==
        DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
      // connected process
    } else if (connectionState.connectionState ==
        DeviceConnectionState.disconnected) {
      print("BLE Disconnect is disconnected");
      onDisconnect(index, true);
    }
  },
  onError: (error) {
    print("BLE Disconnect connection error = $error");
  },
);

This is my background service code.
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  // FlutterReactiveBle flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();

  if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
    service.on('setAsForeground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsForegroundService();
    });
    service.on('setAsBackground').listen((event) {
      service.setAsBackgroundService();
      // print('dolphine $event');
    });
  }
  service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
    service.stopSelf();
  });
}

With this code, when the app restored from background, first service.stopSelf() function is called. And then print("BLE Disconnect is disconnected"); function is called.
I also tried with https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service but I got the same error...
System: Android
Flutter Version: 3.16.7
Package Versions:
flutter_reactive_ble: v5.3.1
flutter_background_service : v5.0.5

Please give me a solution. Thank you.

Till i understood @pragma('vm:entry-point') will only work when app is terminated (Totally closed)
if you are trying to reconnect after app start again from background if possible try this.
@override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        print("app in resumed");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
        print("app in inactive");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        print("app in paused");
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        print("app in detached");
        break;
    }
}

Once you receive the app again active from backStake you can use your code.
to check connectivity and then connect to the device via BLE.
in my case, I am using the same practice and it's working for me.

Thanks, but I got the problem even if i don't put my app in background. For example, I connect my device, i'm starting my service, stopping the service after 5s, and my ble disconnect...

can you try to increase time in connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 5) ???

No no the problem is the "service.stopSelf()" stop the bluetooth...
